# Invoke-ASCmd XMLA Results to storage results in Azure Data Lake with either .csv or .txt format

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I've built an Azure Powershell runbook (5.0) to run a MDX query against a SSAS server , the query is just to get the partition names

```
SELECT 
 [Name]
FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS 
WHERE [Name] <>'Partition'
```

If I run it in SSMS I get the desired results

[image]

The problem comes when I run the query using the powershell runbook because the results are basically an XMLA output

[image]

What I need is the Azure powershell runbook to extract just that column from the $Results variable and then create either a .txt file or .csv in the Azure data lake storage V2 with that data ( like the SSMS). That file will be consumed later by Data Factory.

This is the full script:

```
Param
(
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $Query,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $OperationType,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $ServerName,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $DatabaseName,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $SecretName

)

$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $SecretName

$Results = Invoke-ASCmd -Server $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -Credential $cred -Query $Query

Write-Output $Results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:**

**SSMS:**

`SELECT  [Name] FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS`

[image]
**NOTE:**

Your `$Results` is taking the output as string, you should be converting it to Xml using `[XML]` in PowerShell script.

**Then use below code  instead of your code :**

```
$Results = [XML] (Invoke-ASCmd -Server $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -Credential $cred -Query $Query)
```

**Now use below code:**

```
Write-Output  $Results.return.root.row.Name
```

**Output:**

[image]

You need to incorporate the above 2 codes into your code.After that you need to send the output to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much RithwikBojja , how do I output 2 columns ? I'm planning to create a -txt file with the results